# Using a schrader pump on a presta valve

Tags: pump

I have a JoeBlow Sport (not a Sport II or Sport III)

It head defaults to schrader style. There was an adaptor in the box which I thought was a presta adaptor.

[image: presta adaptor?]

I tried sticking that adaptor in the pump small side (screw side) toward the pump, other on the tire presta value. No matter what I tried I could not get the tire to take air (yes, I unscrewed the lock on the presta valve)

I looked for some videos and the manual but I can find nothing on the JoeBlow Sport. Only the Sport II and Sport III which have a different head.

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6J8D0RLmFo#t0m50s) about some other head and how to change it. It involved opening the head and flipping parts. So I opened the head on my JoeBlow Sport but I can't see any way the parts fit differently.

[image: JoeBlow Sport head parts]

If I flip the second part from the right end, it's black and rubber, it looks like I'd expect for a presta valve but it's impossible to close the head back up with it upside down. In fact I can't see any point in being able to open this head, flipping any piece whatsoever makes it impossible to close.

Can someone explain what I'm supposed to do here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to screw the adaptor on the presta tire valve, then attach the pump head. I was instead putting the adaptor in the head and then pushing it on the value but it needs to be screwed on first.

[image]

I feel dumb but at least my tires are now inflated

Comment: That's the ticket. Chances are, if you've had a query about bikes, someone else will google the same query in the future. Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer (green tick) because it solved the problem